# Rendering second ending closing bar when followed by another repeat in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, repeats

Using LilyPond, I'm engraving some music that consists of two parts that are repeated. The first repeated phrase contains an alternate ending. By default, LilyPond renders the MWE below:

```
\version "2.16.2"

\score {
\new Staff \relative c'' {
    \repeat volta 2 {
        a1 | a
    }
    \alternative{
        { b }
        { a }
    }

    \break

    \repeat volta 2 {
        c1 | c | c | c
    }
}
\layout {}
}
```

like this:

[image: MWE rendered with LilyPond]

This looks alright, except that I would like the second ending to have a double bar line ("||") after it. However, tweaking the MWE above in such a way that one would expect that to happen (`\bar "||"\break\bar "|:"`) results in the same output. Removing the second bar and only putting the double bar before (or after) the break (eg. `\bar "||"\break`) results in:

[image: Rendering of the tweaked MWE illustrating the problem]

LilyPond doesn't seem to understand that it actually makes sense to have both bars (since I've manually inserted a break between the two measures).

*Is there a way to force the bar engraver to output both bars?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just after posting, I found the answer to my own question in the Lilypond Documentation. For version [2.16](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/notation/bars) (which I'm using):

> In addition, you can specify "||:", which is equivalent to "|:" except
>   at line breaks, where it gives a double bar line at the end of the
>   line and a start repeat at the beginning of the next line.

so one would write:

```
\break\bar "||:"
```

For version [2.17](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/notation/bars) (unstable / development) it is currently:

> In addition, you can specify ".|:-||", which is equivalent to ".|:"
>   except at line breaks, where it gives a double bar line at the end of
>   the line and a start repeat at the beginning of the next line.

eg:

```
\break\bar ".|:-||"
```

Comment: It's so weird that ".|:-||" is the new way! To write "||:" or even ".||:" is more logical to my mind.

Comment: I'm downvoting this only because it's obsolete. In newer versions you can use `\section` as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

LilyPond v2.23 offers a few new commands: The `\section` command provides an elegant solution for printing double bar lines — and it works straight-out-of-the-box when adjacent to repeat barlines.

```
\section\break
```

see: [1.2.5 Bars - Automatic bar lines](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/bars#automatic-bar-lines)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is putting `\bar ":|." \break` at the end of the first repeated section.  Then when there should be starting repeat dots, I put

```
\hideNotes \grace{a32} \unHideNotes \bar ".|:"
```

I guess Lilypond internally wants SOMETHING between the two bar lines to make things work.  Apparently a `\break` isn't good enough, but a grace note is.

I'm using Lilypond 2.24.1

Comment: If you post this as a separate question, with enough code to demonstrate the `\section` command not working correctly, you’ll probably get an answer.

Comment: I posted this as a possible solution for the problem described by @user5952.  I'm not sure why you two thought I was asking a question.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to use an invisible grace note for this, so I imagine something else has gone wrong.

Comment: @ElementsInSpace clearly that's so.  I've posted a new question asking about why Lilypond behaves like it does and what a better solution might be.