# Lilypond: how to engrave a double bar at "Fine" when a \repeat statement follows

Tags: lilypond, repeats

Under Lilypond 2.18, the following does not work as expected:

```
\version "2.19.45"

{
g b c r-"Fine" \bar "|." \break
\tempo "Trio"
\repeat volta 2 {
c a f f }
}
```

The double bar at "Fine" fails to appear. The line closes with a regular bar.

I saw the discussion at [Rendering second ending closing bar when followed by another repeat in Lilypond](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/14125/20070), and the hint in the manual to use `\bar ".|:-||"`. However, no variation of the above yields the desired outcome.

Comment: Can you post a small, complete example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I guess, the problem is, that while you specify how the next bar should look like, you never specify the position where this happens. In my opinion a *|* should do. The *\break* statement is concerned with page breaks and has no automatic relation to bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem appeared in a multi-staff score. Usage of `\repeat` was not uniform across staffs. When correcting this, the closing double bar printed correctly.

Comment: It would be useful if you include a full code snippet here in the answer that solved the issue. Also you can accept your own answer. This way it will be a good reference for others that may have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

As of LilyPond v2.23, there are new ways to enter repeats and related structure, including some barlines.

This page of the documentation explains the new syntax:
[1.4.1 Long repeats](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/long-repeats)

```
\version "2.23.6"
{
    \repeat segno 2 {
        g b c r |
        \volta 2 {
            \fine
        }
        \break
        
        \section
        \sectionLabel "Trio"
        \repeat volta 2 {
            c a f f |
        }
    }
}
```

[image: image from above code, showing repeat structure]